# Flutter Display value from Realtime Database. Got Index Error

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I just started using flutter for web. Currently I'm trying to display data from realtime database. and this is the code that fetch the data and display it.

```
class Company extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DatabaseReference refe = database().ref('Company');
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: database().ref('Company').onValue,
        builder: (context, snap) {
          if (snap.hasData) {
            List key1 = [];
            List item1 = [];
            int len;
            refe.once("value").then(
              (data) {
                len = data.snapshot.numChildren();
                var a = data.snapshot.toJson();
                a.forEach(
                  (key, values) {
                    key1.add(key);
                    item1.add(values);
                  },
                );
              },
            );

            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: len,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      child: Card(child: Text(item1[index]['compName'])),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Card(child: Text(item1[index]['companyID'])),
                    ),

                    //Text('Company Name'),
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          } else
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The code itself runs fine but i got an error just below the results i display.

[Displayed the data but have flutter error below it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNIf9.png)

> The following IndexError was thrown building: RangeError (index): Index
> out of range: index should be less than 25: 25

Does anyone know the reason for the error?

Comment: Your var len (in listview itemcount) don’t have the same number of element in a. Your can use item1.length. Remember, array begin in 0. Sometime you have 1 element and try get the array[1] but the begin in 0

Comment: Yup found the problem there. Thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, that's actually a simple problem. as @ClaudioCastro said, you're trying to access an item out of range, it happens when you have an array (list) and you try to access an item that is not available in it. For example:

```
List list = [1, 2, 3] // index 0, 1, 2
```

if you try to access an element that doesn't exist:

```
print(list[3]) // RangeError (index): Index out of range
```

As @ClaudioCastro also said, this is coming from your ListView builder which you are probably giving a higher number to the `itemCount` than you should.

Try to print the value of `len` and `item1.length`, so then check if you get the same result.

Comment: Yup. I print it out and it seems i have a higher number of itemCount. Managed to fix it . Thanks man.